# Chinese characters ending up blank in Database

Tags: php, encoding, mysqli, utf-8, character-encoding

Im making an API for a company that inserts orders via this api into our DB, but I'm running into a problem:

**Chinese characters don't get stored into my tables, how to fix this?**

I have:
- My test file which uses cURL to post set to utf8 via header*
- The API code which inserts the data set to utf8 via header*
- Stored my phpfile as an UTF-8 encoded file
- mysqli connection set to utf8 (`$connection->set_charset("utf8")`)
- mysql-database set to `utf8_general_ci`
- mysql-table set to `utf8_general_ci`
- mysql-columns set to `utf8_general_ci`
- I insert the values into a VARCHAR and into a TEXT column (for test purposes)
- Inserted the values directly into the query -> no result
- Inserted the values via `iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8", $text)`-> weird result
- Inserted the values via `iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8", $text)`-> no result
- Tested characters like `áéíúó`, which work perfectly fine
- Set my postvalues for curl via `foreach($post as $k=>$v){ $data.= $k.'='.$v;}` to send as data
- Set my postvalues for curl via `http_build_query($post)` to send as data
- Used a query before inserted doing `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`
- Used a query before inserted doing `SET NAMES 'utf8'`

1. When I echo the query before inserting it, I see the chinese characters
2. When I check the database, it's blank values
3. (not unexpected:) When I Select it and output it, it's blank

*PHP charset header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

I'm out of ideas, anyone?

Comment: Any changes you if run this before sending anything to the db `SET NAMES 'utf8'`?

Comment: Just tried, no result

Comment: Can you show use the table definition?I only see charset nothing about collation

Comment: Please do `SELECT HEX(col), col ...` so we can see a value that is failing to display correctly.  There are several possible things going wrong; this will help in focusing us.  See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll

Comment: Had a similar problem, and yes, the characters just went poof without any trace or notice. In my case it turns out that utf-8 really isn't the whole monty. I needed utf8mb - set in column/table, character set, names, etc. So, make sure your kind of utf8 really contains what you are inserting.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and use this query and my problem solved 
("SET CHARACTER SET utf8")

```
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8")
```

Comment: As you can see, I have a `set_charset()` in the list of things I did. I will try this anyway, but I doubt it :)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the field has utf8_unicode_ci

```
 CREATE TABLE `table` (
      `id` int(15) NOT NULL,
      `fieldname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and the charset is utf8

```
    mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

OOP

```
public function open_connection() {

    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            $msg = "Database connection failed: ";
            $msg .= mysqli_connect_error();
            $msg .= " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")";
            exit($msg);
        }
        // Change character set to utf8
        mysqli_set_charset($this->connection,"utf8");

      }
```